# Is it a good approach to split admin API and public API which share some similar functionality?

Tags: spring-boot, api, web-applications, admin

I am a Computer Science student. Me and couple of my course mates were given a project of creating a web app that would allow to search for all university graduates. The web app should have a search frontend and an administrative interface where admins could manage the graduate data (basic CRUD application I guess) as well as other users of the interface. The administrative interface must only be accessible with our university specific accounts, so it should have RBAC and similar security-related things. On the public search, however, this is not needed. Both public search and administrative interface should implement a graduate search functionality, just handle it differently (different accessible filters for example)

We decided to create a Spring Boot application for that along with Angular frontend, but I guess this is not very relevant. The problem we face is whether we split our public search API from the admin API. Currently we have two opinions:

1. There is no point in splitting since search should be implemented in both public side and administrative side, the only difference is ability to apply different filters, since public search should only display limited amount of information. This would allow us to create one search component (for example using Spring Specifications and Criteria API) and just provide it with different filter parameters. Also splitting would mean duplication of some parts like Model classes.
2. Since public search should only display and filter based on limited data, it wouldn't be nice to mix two solutions in one. We should split the admin backend and public backend into two separate projects *per se*, because lots of components like authorization, DTOs, user management are not needed for public search and thus it would not be nice to mix those two.

I hope I described the problem in an understandable way. Sorry for long text and hope someone can explain what would be the best approach.

Comment: This question would be a best fit for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @AsifKamranMalick when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)